# Jenkins configuration on on-premise hosts

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have a jenkins node that I am currently using as a build node. The workspace directory of the pipeline is set to "C:\workspacedir"

And I have recently added a new node and this node doesnot have a C:\ Drive . Is there any way i can use a wildcard expression instead of pointing to a specific drive ?

Answer (score 0):

Under Jenkins | Manage Jenkins | Manage Nodes | | Configure ...
There is an option to set

`Remote root directory [       ]`.

That is where you override the default. It is the `remoteFS`

The [Configuration as Code](https://plugins.jenkins.io/configuration-as-code/) plugin has the following configuration example:

```
nodes:
- permanent:
    name: "static-agent"
    remoteFS: "/home/jenkins"
```